# Flutter Local Notification Issue with One Plus Device

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications, flutter-notification

The example code https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notification  works differently in native devices and Chinese devices.

The notification sound does not come in one plus 7T that is Android 30 also the notification UI does not come on top of the front screen it directly falls in the notification tray.

While on a Device like Nokia 5.1 Plus Android 29 it works perfectly fine.

The example code works differently in native devices and Chinese devices.

The notification sound does not come in one plus 7T that is Android 30 also the notification UI does not come in front of the screen it directly falls in the notification tray.
Only show Grouped notification come above the screen while all other notification falls directly in the system tray

While on a Device like Nokia 5.1 Plus Android 29 it works perfectly fine.

When Disabling battery optimization Permission the sound comes. however, this only works for InboxStyleInformation while for BigPictureStyleInformation the sound does not come, and also notification is not coming above the screen it falls in the system tray

Is there any separate config that has to be done or do we need to create a native android notification code and use it as a custom lib?

Comment: Try setting `importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high`, while scheduling notification.